# How to generate a list of filenames?

Tags: python, list

I am struggling in generating a list of file names. I want a list of files which are like file_1.txt file_2.txt etc.

I did the following

```
x= ['file_']
y= range(1,57)
z= x + y
```

I expected `z` will be like `file_1.txt`, `file_2.txt` and so on but something else happened.  How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use list comprehension here:

```
z = ['file_%s'%y for y in range(1,57)]
```

And this generates:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> z = ['file_%s'%y for y in range(1,57)]
>>> z
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5', 'file_6', 'file_7', 'file_8', 'file_9', 'file_10', 'file_11', 'file_12', 'file_13', 'file_14', 'file_15', 'file_16', 'file_17', 'file_18', 'file_19', 'file_20', 'file_21', 'file_22', 'file_23', 'file_24', 'file_25', 'file_26', 'file_27', 'file_28', 'file_29', 'file_30', 'file_31', 'file_32', 'file_33', 'file_34', 'file_35', 'file_36', 'file_37', 'file_38', 'file_39', 'file_40', 'file_41', 'file_42', 'file_43', 'file_44', 'file_45', 'file_46', 'file_47', 'file_48', 'file_49', 'file_50', 'file_51', 'file_52', 'file_53', 'file_54', 'file_55', 'file_56']
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a *list comprehension* along with the usage of `str.format` as:

```
#           v `{}` will be replaced with value of `i` with each iteration
>>> ['file_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,5)]
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the list of your file name, use a list and a for loop along with string formatting. Then if you need to do something with the file name, just access the list.

```
fileList = []

for i in range(0,5):
     fileList.append("File_%s" %i)

print(fileList)

#Output: ['File_0.txt', 'File_1.txt', 'File_2.txt', 'File_3.txt', 'File_4.txt']
```